# XHR response has wrong data in callback

Tags: javascript, json, callback

I am currently trying to write a simple application, that requests data from the server via multiple asynchronous xhr requests. The response is handled in the onreadystatechanged callbacks for each request.

Currently if i do more than ~10 requests asynchronously, i start getting wrong data from the requests callbacks, aka:

```
book 1: abc --> correct
book 2: efg --> correct
book 3: efg --> wrong
book 4: kjl --> correct
```

I worked my way back to the onreadystatehandler, and even here the request object contains the wrong data ( req.responseText ). 
The urls (req.responseURL ) are correct, as in each url requested gets callbacked once, just with the wrong data.

So i took a look in the browser devtools at the responses I received to verify that indeed the correct data was given from the server, which is the case.

I honestly have no ideas left on how to fix this, as the server is responding with correct data, but the requests callback just "use" the wrong one, even though having the correct urls.

This is how i try to achieve it:

```
var sendRequest = function(url, callback){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    if(callback) {
        req.onreadystatechange = (function(req,callback){
            return function() {
                if(req.readyState == 4) {
                    if(req.status == 200 || req.status == 304) {

                        var response;
                        try {
                            response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                        } catch(error) {
                            callback(undefined, req.responseText);
                            return;
                        }

                        if(response.error)
                            callback(response.error, response);
                        else
                            callback(undefined, response);

                    }else{
                        callback("Error", req.responseText)
                    }
                }
            };
        })(req,callback);
    }
    req.send(params);
}
```

Here is a sample of code i use for sending the requests.

```
var booksToLoad = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < libraries.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    sendRequest('/LibraryList?'+'Id='+libraries[i]._id, function(err, response) {
        libraries[i] = response.library;    
        booksToload += libraries[i].books.length;
        for(var j=0; j < libraries[i].books.length; j++) {
            (function (i, j) {                          
                sendRequest('/BookList?'+'Id='+libraries[i].books[j]._id, function (err, response) {
                    libraries[i].books[j].pages = response.pages;
                    --booksToLoad;
                    if(booksToLoad == 0)
                        return;
                });
            })(i, j);
        }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Things i have tried:

1. Turn the for loops into recursive calls --> Works, but WAY to slow.
2. Store requests in array and iterate over that to send --> not working
3. Check if JSON.parse() somehow breaks it --> nope plain data also wrong
4. force no caching with header --> not working
5. tried different browser ( chrome + firefox ) --> not working

As written before, i am puzzled by the fact that the data from the server is fine AND the callbacks get called with the correct req.responseURL BUT with the wrong data (not taken from the url inside the response ).

Thanks for your help, i am at loss here...

Maggistro

---

EDIT: I kinda gave up and decided is was bad design anyway to send this amount of xhr requests. So i bundled the requests together ( whole library at once, containing books + pages ).

That way if the package gets to big later on, i am forced to manage my requested data (where i have full control), instead of the amount of requests permitted by browser.

Dont know if this is a good idea, but i cant loose more time on this problem.
Still like to know exactly what causes this behaviour for future reference.

Thanks for your time,

Maggistro

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function fetchLibrary(i){
    sendRequest('/LibraryList?Id='+libraries[i]._id, function(err, response) {
        libraries[i] = response.library;    
        for(var j=0; j < libraries[i].books.length; j++)
            fetchBooks(i,j);
    });
}

function fetchBooks(i,j){                         
    sendRequest('/BookList?Id='+libraries[i].books[j]._id, function (err, response) {
        libraries[i].books[j].pages = response.pages;
    });
}

for(var i = 0; i < libraries.length; i++) {
    fetchLibrary(i);
}
```

And, use the network tab to make sure that the requests that are being sent do return the proper results. If they do not (check the response), fix your server side fetch component.

==========

Ok, here is fully tested and functional example of both server side and client side component. Use that as a reference:

Server side (service.php):

```
<?php


$libraries = [
    ["id" => 1, "name" => "foo"],
    ["id" => 2, "name" => "bar"],
    ["id" => 3, "name" => "baz"]
];

$books = [
    ["library_id" => 1, "id" => 1, "pages" => 10],
    ["library_id" => 1, "id" => 2, "pages" => 11],
    ["library_id" => 1, "id" => 3, "pages" => 12],
    ["library_id" => 2, "id" => 4, "pages" => 13],
    ["library_id" => 2, "id" => 4, "pages" => 14],
    ["library_id" => 2, "id" => 5, "pages" => 15],
    ["library_id" => 3, "id" => 6, "pages" => 16],
    ["library_id" => 3, "id" => 7, "pages" => 17],
    ["library_id" => 3, "id" => 8, "pages" => 18]
];
header("Content-type: application/json;encoding=utf-8");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["request_id"])){
    $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0');
    header($protocol . ' 500 Error - Specify Request ID');
    exit;
}
$request_id  = $_REQUEST["request_id"];
$library_id = isset($_REQUEST["library_id"])?$_REQUEST["library_id"]:null;

$ret = [];
if ($library_id){
    // fetch list of books for the library_id
    foreach ($books as $book){
        if ($book["library_id"] == $library_id){
            $ret[] = $book;
        }
    }
} else {
    // fetch list of libraries
    $ret = $libraries;
}
print_r(json_encode(["request_id" => $request_id, "result" => $ret], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Client side:

```
<script>
function r(url, callback){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.responseType = "json";
    url += url.match(/\?/)?"&":"?";
    var request_id = new Date().getTime();
    url += "request_id=" + request_id; 
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            status = req.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                console.log("URL " + url + " received", req.response);
                callback(req.response, request_id);
            } else {
                window.alert("Problem with request " + url);
                console.error(url + " failed. Status: " + status);
                console.log(req.response);
            }
        }
    }
    req.send();
}

function fetchLibraries(){
    r("service.php", function(data, id){
        for (var x in data.result){
            fetchBooks(data.result[x]);
        }
    });
}

function fetchBooks(library){
    var e = document.createElement("p");
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.innerHTML = "loading " + library.id;
    r("service.php?library_id=" + library.id, function(data){
        e.innerHTML = "";
        for (var x in data.result){
            var book = data.result[x];
            e.innerHTML += "Book: " + book.id + ", pages: " + book.pages + "<br>";
        }
    });
}

fetchLibraries();
</script>
```

Fully tested, works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. Tried it, did not change a thing. Network tab contains correct results, so server side is working fine.

Comment: Added a fully functional example for you. Enjoy.

Comment: I took your example ( client side ) and adapted my structure to it. Sadly it behaves the same way as before. Server responses are still correct, client side fetches wrong data for each url.

Comment: I added request_id, so that you can explicitly check what you sent and what you receive in the frontend. do some debugging - check what you are getting in the javascript methods themselves. the above code does not have any issues, so it must be your particular front-end implementation that is causing issues.

Comment: I checked the contents of the network tab, they are correct. If i check the methods callback ( for loops ) i get the wrong data for the id. If i go up the stack trace i see that this data originates from the req.onreadystatechange callback, with the same id (from url) and the same wrong data. I need go further up into the implementation of the xhr request until i see when exactly the data is read from the response and stored inside the xhr request object, but i dont exactly know where to look.

Comment: have you tried using exactly the methods that I have suggested? also, share the url to your project (minimum part that has the error)